# Exporting a script variable using `sh -cx`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to export a variable from a script in the following manner:

`sh -xc "<script here>"`

But cannot get it to work at all. I've tried several techniques such as:

`sh -xc "./xxx.sh"`(exporting a variable yyy from the file itself)

`sh -xc "./xxx.sh && export yyy=1"`
(had xxx.sh exit 0)

`sh -xc ". ./xxx.sh"`

As well as several permutations of the above, but no dice on any of them.

Unfortunately, I must conform to the `sh -xc "<script here>"` style. Any script I execute will be placed inside of the quotations, file and/or command(s). There's no way around this.

Is what I'm asking even possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an export through a shell script, because a shell script runs in a child shell process, and only children of the child shell would inherit the export.

The reason for using source is to have the current shell execute the commands

It's very common to place export commands in a file such as `.bashrc` which a bash will source on startup (or similar files for other shells)

But you can do as follows:

```
shell$ cat > script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo export myTest=success

chmod u+x script.sh
```

And then have the current shell execute that output

```
  shell$ `./script.sh`

  shell$ echo $myTest
  success

  shell$ /bin/sh
  $ echo $myTest
  success
```

Comment: That's a roundabout way of doing it.  There's no need to add `echo`; the file `script2.sh` could be just: `export myTest2=improved` (though it could contain any number of lines), and you could execute its contents using the `.` command (or, in Bash, the `source` command): `. ./script2.sh` and then you could do `echo $myTest2`.  This is the normal way to export variables in the current shell with a script; this is logically what the shell does at startup with profiles, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right, but the `.` or `source` commands do not seem to work, though, when executed as follows `sh -cx ". ./myscript.sh"`. As said earlier, `sh -cx "<script here>"` is an unfortunate requirement.

Comment: @JKB This solution does not work when executed with `sh -cx`. But it does work when executed regularly, as you've just posted. I really need the former style to work.

Comment: @user3331320: In that case, you are snookered.  I believe it should be `-xc` rather than `-cx` as `-cx` treats the name `x` as a script to be executed.  About as close as you will be able to get then is the echo trick JKB used: `$(sh -xc "echo export EnvVar=SomeValue")` or the equivalent using backticks (not the preferred notation).  But it is messy — and probably disallowed by the obscure rules you're working under.  A child process can't change its parent's environment; a parent could use the output from the child to change its environment. The `.` command does not create a child process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you are right formally it's not needed `echo` just `export` also work but that's what i write in my  script and @user3331320 it's hard as you want but like ``sh script.sh`` way is not much bad.